# Rails number_field_tag won't accept a float even with :step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a number of entry fields laid out in a table, and one of the entries is:

```
<td><%= number_field_tag :elasticity, :step => 0.1 %></td>
```

When I enter a non-integer value such as 1.3 and try to post the form, it pops up with "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 1 and 2". The up and down arrows increment by 1, too, not 0.1.

The HTML that is being produced is:

```
<td><input id="elasticity" name="elasticity" type="number" value="{:step=&gt;0.1}" /></td>
```

So I can't see why it's not accepting non-integer values. Can anybody suggest what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to [`number_field_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L738) is `value` which is why you are seeing `value="{:step=&gt;0.1}"`.

Call the helper as follows:

```
<td><%= number_field_tag :elasticity, nil, :step => 0.1 %></td>
```

Comment: Love it when it's something simple! Thanks.